# Creating a "dropdown" from an input field as user types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input-field

I am trying to re-create this drop down area that gets created as a user starts searching:

[image]

I have tried searching for how to achieve this and haven't found exactly what I am looking for maybe because I do not know how to even word what I am searching for. What would this type of drop down be called? I am using reactjs and am wondering if there's anything out there that already exists like this that I could start with.

Answer (score 0):

i think is a kind of navbar, maybe can you read the [react doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/?)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp
Just style it like you want to and add filter results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to create custom filter search for that, in react js you can do that in following way as an example: 

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mtclmn/pen/QyPVJp)